# My Xcode Build in iTunes Connect is not showing my app or to connect. How do I fix it?

Tags: app-store-connect

I archived and uploaded my app through Xcode 9. However, I don't see it on iTunes Connect. Any advice?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0zoc.png)

Comment: When did you add it? It needs some time till your upload is visible in iTunes Connect.

Comment: Thank you! I got the email and it works now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can take a couple hours for it to appear in iTunes connect

Answer (score 1):

Normally, it will take 15 mins max. Sometimes it taking 1 hour.

But, if you uploaded build with some issue, then it will not showing on iTunes. In that case, you will get an email with registered email address. You required to solve than issue and upload build again.